Copyright status of arrangements produced for purpose of producing compulsory-licensed recordings
If someone wants to produce a musical recording under a compulsory mechanical license, using instrumentation other than that for which the piece was originally composed, it will often be necessary to do some level of musical arrangement.  By my understanding, although the original copyright older would have no authority to forbid an arrangement they didn't like, the person who acquires the license would (in the absence of additional licensure) only be allowed to treat the phonorecord that was produced under license, and not any underlying aspects of the arranged musical composition, as a derived work of their own.
Would this imply that as a consequence no aspects of that arranged composition could ever be treated as being a work separate from the original?  If so, would there be any mechanism via which someone could discover whether a recording of an arrangement piece that has lapsed into the public domain was copyrighted (as would be the case if the arranger had licensed the arrangement prior to making the recording) or non-copyrightable (as would seem to be the case otherwise)?  Copyright notices, when present, could be helpful, but unfortunately there are no notice requirements.  What must one do to safely borrow musical elements from recorded arrangements of public domain pieces, either for producing one's own recordings, or for publishing transcriptions?

I am not even sure that you are allowed to do a different arrangement under a compulsory mechanical license...

@Trish: Arrangements which substantially alter the nature of a composition are not allowed under a compusory license, but a compulsory license doesn't require matching the original version of a song note-for-note.  If e.g. a saxophone quartet covers a piano piece that sometimes has five notes playing at once, the group would be allowed to exercise judgment as to which notes should be played, and by which instruments, rather than having to hire a fifth performer to play in those spots.

@Trish: Suppose, for example, that Scott Joplin's "The Entertainer" was still under copyright.  The left hand and right hands play very different rhytms, and there are some places where it would make sense to have everyone but the soprano sax follow the left-hand rhythm, others where it would make more sense to have everyone but the baritone follow the right hand rhythm, and some where it would probably make the most sense to have baritone and tenor play the left hand while alto and soprano play the right.  Making such divisions may or may not be seen as producing an "arrangment".
